# UIView animation doesn't get stuck but UIButton does when blocking main thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, animation, swift3

I have a simple animated rectangle on screen generated in code.

```
let rect = UIView()
self.view.addSubview(rect)
rect.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
rect.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0.0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
    rect.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)
}, completion: { finished in

})
```

There are two buttons on screen: one triggers `self.didPressStuckIt` and another one triggers `self.didPressDoNotStuckIt`. My intension is to pause the animation by running simulated heavy computation on main thread, and do not pause the animation when I run the heavy computation in another thread.

```
@IBAction func didPressStuckIt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let runId = arc4random_uniform(10000000)
    sleep(4)
    statusLabel.text = "Status: didPressStuckIt Completed (\(runId))"
}

@IBAction func didPressDoNotStuckIt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let runId = arc4random_uniform(10000000)
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myqueue", qos: .default, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: DispatchQueue.AutoreleaseFrequency.never, target: nil)
    queue.async {
        sleep(4)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.statusLabel.text = "Status: didPressDoNotStuckIt Complted (\(runId))"
        }
    }
}
```

When I trigger `didPressDoNotStuckIt`, things work like what I expected. The button itself worked as normal and the animation kept going on.

The weird part is `didPressStuckIt`. The button got stuck and remained unresponsive since the computation was blocking the main thread, but the animation was still running smoothly.

Can anybody explain why the animation was not stuck?

Comment: Hi John - as I understand it Apple uses a dedicated animation server that runs on its own thread.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html, particularly the section entitled "Starting Animations using the Begin/Commit Methods" which briefly goes into why animation is set up so as not to interrupt the main thread.